# disable auto-complete in file type in sublime text 2

Tags: sass, sublimetext2

Is there any way of disabling the default snippet/autocomplete options in a file type? I'm currently using [hayaku](http://hayakubundle.com) to speed up my sass/scss writing and I find that the default snippets keep getting in my way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the defaults by setting your own snippets with the same keyword. You can also set a file scope to affect only specific ones so the rest of your Sublime still works normally (If that's your thing).

Also from looking at their [github page](https://github.com/hayaku/hayaku), you can set a few options in this file to suit your needs: [Preferences.sublime-settings](https://github.com/hayaku/hayaku/blob/master/Preferences.sublime-settings)

Here's how you can make a snippet:
http://www.webtempest.com/sublime-text-2-how-to-create-snippets/

Comment: hmm... It seems like it is doing it already then, according to this `"disable_tab_abbreviations_for_scopes": "css,less,sass,scss,stylus"`

Comment: Yes, that disables expanding abbreviation by Tab key for those files. This is a “dark side” of having such a convenient feature - it overrides default snippets. The ultimate idea is to store all your html/css snippets in hayaku. They should include a line to honor original snippets but unfortunately I didn't see one.

Comment: snippet tutorial link is broken. It just needs 'www' like this: http://www.webtempest.com/sublime-text-2-how-to-create-snippets/